# Visual Studio Community 2013 Parenthesis

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I just starting using Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition, and there's a really, really annoying feature that I don't know how to get rid of: if I start typing code on a new line, the editor immediately adds () where my cursor is.  No matter what.  Even when it makes no sense (e.g. I'm not calling a function).

Is there any way to get rid of that?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the Tools.Options menu's Text Editor.<language> settings.

Comment: Tried all the options in there, can't find what's making this happen...

Comment: Try resetting settings, I haven't seen that happen. `Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings`

Comment: I'll try.  It was a fresh install on a new EC2 instance.  I'm wondering if it's something that's happening "lost in translation" over RDP